# what is `modified_timestamp` used for in plotly store component

Tags: plotly, store, plotly-dash

I am reading about the first example on https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/store

why

```
@app.callback(Output('{}-clicks'.format(store), 'children'),
              [Input(store, 'modified_timestamp')],
              [State(store, 'data')])
def on_data(ts, data):
    if ts is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    data = data or {}

    return data.get('clicks', 0)
```

instead of

```
@app.callback(Output('{}-clicks'.format(store), 'children'),
              [Input(store, 'data')])
def on_data(data):
    data = data or {}
    return data.get('clicks', 0)
```

I don't understand the reason for using `modified_timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs page you shared:

> Retrieving the initial store data
>
> If you use the data prop as an output, you cannot get the initial data on load with the data prop. To counter this, you can use the `modified_timestamp` as Input and the data as State.
>
> This limitation is due to the initial None callbacks blocking the true data callback in the request queue.
>
> See https://github.com/plotly/dash-renderer/pull/81 for further discussion.

Comment: I see, but this is a bit hard to understand without knowledge of react, seems.

Comment: I've done programming in react, but still don't fully understand

Comment: I agree, it is a bit confusing. The easiest way I can think of it is just that this is the proper way to use the prop, because trying to use it differently wouldn't work properly.